# How to use `getAttr` to get the color name in Maya scripts?

Tags: python, maya

How can I get this string attribute? (ColorName)

[image]

```
from maya import cmds

print cmds.getAttr('Dashboard.Color')
```

I only get "1" when it is Blue and get "0" when it is Green.

Comment: What is this `Dashboard`? Is it a normal maya node?

Comment: created by myself

Comment: So what type of attribute it your Dashboard.Color attribute? Is it a color? If yes you should get a 3 color valure as result and you should be able to request e.g the red value with `Dashboard.ColorR`.

Comment: all items (Dashboard, color, green...etc) were defined by myself, so it isn't the color attribute in maya

Comment: I want to get the string in this attribute

Answer (score 0):

If your attribute is an enum you need to use the "asString" flag to get the string value.

```
from maya import cmds
print cmds.getAttr('Dashboard.Color', asString=True)
```

The [Maya Technical Documentation](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/index.html) is a pretty good source of information. Here's the relevant part of the [getAttr](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/getAttr.html) documentation:

> asString(asString)
>
> This flag is only valid for enum attributes. It allows you to get the attribute values as strings instead of integer values.